# KML line from pin with given azimuth

Tags: kml

I have the coordinates of a point and an azimuth. 
I want to place a pin in the coordinate of the point, and draw a line segment of a certain length L beginning from the point, and oriented in a certain given azimuth.
Is there a simple manner to do that in KML?

I do not want to calculate the coordinate of the second point to draw the segment.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no way to do a calculation in kml itself so the line segment end point would have to be calculated before the construction of the kml or as kml supplied from a server. So the short answer would seem to be that it is not possible.

However I wonder if you could create a model consisting of the line of known length and orientation and plot the 'model' at the pin position. This of course would allow construction of much more sophisticated lines with arrow heads or planes extending to ground etc.

I tried a quick example using Google Sketchup and it seems to work OK

Hope this helps

Bob J.

Answer (score 0):

KML does not do calculations for you.  You'll need to do the calculation yourself.